# Nest.js cache in k8s with several replicas

Tags: kubernetes, caching, nestjs

I didn't find any information related to my concern but, as I understand, if we have a Nest.js application running in k8s with several replicas setup (let's say 3), each `app/pod/node` would have it's own cache and if we use cache manager of Nest.js to `store/get` some data there might be a situation when we won't be able to get stored data because the request goes to another replica. Am I correct or it doesn't work like that? If yes - how can I avoid such situation?